# Change heroku region after creation

Tags: heroku, region

Thought this could work, but it doesn't:

```
 heroku appname --region=eu
```

This works, but I already have an existing app, so this does not make sense for me:

```
heroku create --region eu
```

Or for an addon:

```
heroku addons:list --region=eu
```

Answer (score 11):

There is NO native ability just to switch region, but still there is a way how to do this.

Create fork of the app in a region you need.
For example, you have app in US region and you want to migrate it to EU:

- The heroku fork command is no longer included with the Heroku CLI by default, but it is available via a plugin with the following command:

  ```
  heroku plugins:install heroku-fork
  ```
- Run this command to create a new app that will be a copy of existing:

  ```
  heroku fork --from sourceapp --to targetapp --region eu
  ```
- After check if it is working, check (and copy-paste if needed) settings, permissions, addons, etc. They might copy too, but it is better to check.
- Rename `sourceapp` to something like `sourceapp_old`.
- Rename `targetapp` to `sourceapp`.

NOTE: But still this method has few cons:

- it doesn't migrate database (but there is a [method how to handle that](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/app-migration#database-preparation))
- there can be issues with DNS and SSL
- if the web server is live - you'll need to [use maintenance mode](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/app-migration#maintenance-mode)

Anyhow, I'd recommend to read [official Heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/app-migration#fork-application) before doing so risky actions like this.

Comment: 2021 / The heroku fork command is no longer included with the Heroku CLI by default: `heroku plugins:install heroku-fork`

Comment: also this plugin unmaintained and failed for me

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by forking your app. Have a look at the Heroku documentation here:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/app-migration

Comment: it can not be used if the app already exist and I don't want to delete it.